# DNN (DotNetNuke) Website project throws error "Install.aspx could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I've downloaded the full source-code version of DotNetNuke (v.9.0) .

When I try to build the DNN website on my local computer using Visual Studio (2015) via loading the project provided -- `DotNetNuke.Website.csproj` in the **Website** folder-- I get the following errors:

```
Error CS2001 Source file 'C:\...\Website\Install\Install.aspx.cs' could not be found.
Error CS2001 Source file 'C:\...\Website\Install\UpgradeWizard.aspx.cs' could not be found.
```

The only solution I've found so far has been to load all of the Website folder as a website into a new solution. Yet I would prefer to have a proper Web Project instead.

Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time searching for a solution, I've found one:

1. Open the provided Web project `DotNetNuke.Website.csproj` in Visual Studio (I'm using 2015)
2. Right click on the project and select "Unload"
3. Now right click again on the unloaded project and click "Edit". This will open an xml file
4. Search for "Install.aspx" and "UpgradeWizard.aspx" and remove the references for these files

   ```
   <Compile Include="Install\Install.aspx.cs">
   <DependentUpon>install.aspx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Install\Install.aspx.designer.cs">
   <DependentUpon>install.aspx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Install\UpgradeWizard.aspx.cs">
   <DependentUpon>UpgradeWizard.aspx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Install\UpgradeWizard.aspx.designer.cs">
   <DependentUpon>UpgradeWizard.aspx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   ```
5. Also, search for `<Install>true</Install>` and set it to **false**.
6. Right click on the project and Load it into the solution.

Now DNN website should run without problems.

I hope this helps someone.